# Jquery Array duplicate records inside the tr iterate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

### My Table & Code

```
NewsNo GeoLoc
------ ------
1       US
2       UK
3       GER


var GloablArr = [];

$("#btnRefUp").click(function () {

   var newssArr = {};
    $("#ntbl > tbody > tr").each(function () {

        newssArr['NewsNo']  = $(this).find('td :eq(0)').val();
        newssArr['GeoLoc']  = $(this).find('td :eq(1)').val();

        GloablArr.push(newssArr) <-- GlobalArr shows the final item(s) only.

    });

});
```

But my results come like this(GlobalArr),
3  GER
3  GER
3  GER

Comment: you are updating same object again and again

Comment: Initialize `var newssArr = {};` inside  loop.

Comment: `<td>` elements haven't a value. they have a `text()` or `html()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the same object again and again instead you need to initialize object inside the callback function of each method.

```
var GloablArr = [];

$("#btnRefUp").click(function() {
  $("#ntbl > tbody > tr").each(function() {
    var newssArr = {};
    newssArr['NewsNo'] = $(this).find('td :eq(0)').val();
    newssArr['GeoLoc'] = $(this).find('td :eq(1)').val();
    GloablArr.push(newssArr) 
  });
});
```

---

Or directly generate object and push to the array.

```
var GloablArr = [];

$("#btnRefUp").click(function() {
  $("#ntbl > tbody > tr").each(function() {
    GloablArr.push({
      NewsNo: $(this).find('td :eq(0)').val(),
      GeoLoc: $(this).find('td :eq(1)').val()
    })
  });
});
```

---

You can even simplify the code by using [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method instead of [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) method.

```
var GloablArr;

$("#btnRefUp").click(function() {
  GloablArr = $("#ntbl > tbody > tr").map(function() {
    return {
      NewsNo: $(this).find('td :eq(0)').val(),
      GeoLoc: $(this).find('td :eq(1)').val()
    };
  }).get(); // get the result as array
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only ever creating a *reference* to `newsArr` - thereafter you're pushing the same properties to it and pushing another reference each time to your global array.

A simple fix is to recreate a new object each iteration of `each`

```
$("#ntbl > tbody > tr").each(function () {
    var newssArr = {};
    newssArr['NewsNo']  = $(this).find('td :eq(0)').val();
    newssArr['GeoLoc']  = $(this).find('td :eq(1)').val();

    GloablArr.push(newssArr) <-- GlobalArr shows the final item(s) only.

});
```

A better solution might be to just create all the items for your global array in 1 go

```
var items = $("#ntbl > tbody > tr").map(function () {
    return {
     NewsNo: $(this).find('td :eq(0)').val(),
     GeoLoc: $(this).find('td :eq(1)').val()
    };
}).get();
GloablArr = items;
```